# Why can I access the reader object even though its outside the scope

Tags: python

This is confusing me, from my understanding I have created my reader object inside the with as scope. I don't understand why I can access the reader even though I'm in a different scope I think.

How do you determine scopes in python?

```
with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as file:
    reader = file.read()
    for i in reader:
        sequence.append(i)


for i in range(len(reader)):
    print(i)
```

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify. The scope of identifiers in python is different than most other languages in that an identifier defined in a conditional or loop block is still in scope after the conditional or loop ends. Like other languages scope is still limited to the function its defined in, and also the module (file) it is defined in if its at the top level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the *context* of a context manager and the *scope* of a variable. Python has only 2 scopes: the global scope at file level, and the local scope at **function** level. There is no block level scope like in other languages like C, C++ or Java.

So `reader` does not go out of scope at the end of the `with` block. Only `file` is closed, even if it still remains in scope.

If you want to destroy an object before the end of the function in which it is declared, you must explicitely delete it:

```
with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as file:
    reader = file.read()    # reader will live until end of FUNCTION, or always if global
    for i in reader:
        sequence.append(i)

print(len(reader))          # reader is still in scope here

del reader                  # object is destroyed

print(len(reader))          # raises NameError
```